# Standards in developing microservices with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, microservices

What is a c# microservices? I have found different versions of microservices on the internet.

1. The first one talked about using microServices4Net, l am currently getting an error about the microsoft.owin assembly:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

2. The second one talked abt a code that publishes a message.

What is the original way of creating a microservice, l really want to grasp the concept.

Comment: `l am currentyly getting and error abt the microsoft.owin assembly 2` what error?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such a thing as (C# Microservice).
Microservice does not depend on any programming language. You can have multiple microservices running on different technologies.

In short, the microservice architectural style is an approach to developing a single application as a suite of small services, each running in its own process and communicating with lightweight mechanisms, often an HTTP resource API. (Martin Fowler)

Best Regrads
Burim